# Is it possible to create a TH with TableRow.insertCell()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I'm adding new rows to a table dynamically, with this code:

```
tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
tr = tbody.insertRow(-1);
tr.id = 'last';
th = tr.insertCell(0);
td = tr.insertCell(1);
```

But what I actually got are two `td` cells. I want a `th`, as you can see.

It says the `tagName` property isn't changeable.

How can I do this?

Will I need to use 'normal' methods like `createElement` and `appendChild`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any official docs that allow you to do this.

[W3C Documentation for TR / TR.insertCell](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-6986576)

The `createElement/appendChild` will work though.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work this way:

```
var table = d3.select("#table");
    table.html("");
    head = table.append("tr");
    head.append("th").text("column_header_1");
    head.append("th").text("column_header_2");

    chartData.forEach(function (obj) {
        row = table.append("tr");
        row.append("td").text(obj.datapoint_1);
        row.append("td").text(obj.datapoint_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is define the th first, such as TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
Add cell to it, then add it to the table.

Comment: as you can see by the sample code, i don't wanna a header row, but just a header cell.

Answer (score -2):

a fast and working approch would be using a `<b></b>` tag in the innerHtml

```
tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
tr = tbody.insertRow(-1);
tr.id = 'last';
td = tr.insertCell(1);
th = tr.insertCell(0);
th.innerHtml = '<b>th cell1</b>
th = tr.insertCell(1);
th.innerHtml = '<b>th cell2</b>
//and so on
```