# Looping through code to create `<th>` tags but getting `<td>`

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, innerhtml

This is my code snippet, For every row I am iterating through this array and want to create `<th>` as many times the loop continues. So for example if loops continues 3 times, 3 `<th>` should be created with plan names. But the issue is instead of `<th>` I am having 3 `<td>`.
Please tell where I am going wrong?

```js
for (j = 0; j < bid[j].length; j++) {

  for (k = 0; k < plan["data"].length; k++) {
    if (plan["data"][k]) {
      if (bid[j] == plan["data"][k]) {
        first_row = '<th><b>' + plan["data"][k]["[Plan name]"] + '</b></th>';
        var table = document.getElementById("data");
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = first_row;
        //$("#data").append(first_row); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want something in this way

```html
  
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Where do you set `row`?

Comment: You can't put a row inside a cell.

Comment: insertCell inserts `<td>` elements. There is not a corresponding method for `<th>`, you'd need to use `createElement('th')` and append it to the row.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999927/insert-th-in-thead or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793046/is-it-possible-to-create-a-th-with-tablerow-insertcell

Comment: If in doubt, always check what your method does [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) - `You can not[sic] use insertCell() to create a new <th> element`  (*sic should be cannot)

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a `<th>` inside a table cell. A cell is either a `<td>` or `<th>`. But `insertCell` always creates `<td>` cells. Putting `<th>` inside it doesn't change its type.

Use jQuery to add the `<th>` to the first row of the table.

```js
for (j = 0; j < bid[j].length; j++) {

  for (k = 0; k < plan["data"].length; k++) {
    if (plan["data"][k]) {
      if (bid[j] == plan["data"][k]) {
        $("#data tr:first").append('<th><b>' + plan["data"][k]["[Plan name]"] + '</b></th>'); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: var table = document.getElementById("data");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    $("#data td:first").append('<th><b>Plan Names</b></th>');

Comment: I was trying to use this in another scenario aswell, I am doing this way to create first cell of the row as `<th>`. But again getting `<td>`

Comment: You can't append a `th` to a `td`. That should be `#data tr:first`